# Use of wildcards in a fileref generating Insufficient Authorization message

Tags: sas

Is there a SAS system option, configuration parameter, or other scenario that might disable the use of wildcards in a fileref? The following code works:

```
FILENAME THEFILE "/sasrep/POC/UNGMPW.PRO" ;
data _null_;
    infile thefile;
    input;
run;
```

Whereas the following code:

```
FILENAME THEFILE "/sasrep/POC/UNGMP?.PRO" ;
data _null_;
    infile thefile;
    input;
run;
```

generates this error message:

```
ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access /sasrep/POC/UNGMP?.PRO.
```

This is using SAS 9.1.3 on UNIX.

Comment: Is that the precise error message you get?  I can simulate this error if there is another file in the directory that matches the pattern but does not have read permission.  But the error message I get refers to the specific file (not with the wildcard).

Comment: Yes that's a literal copy and paste.

Comment: Read permission does not seem to be lacking as I can make equivalent code without wildcards work.

Comment: Sorry I can't help; it works for me.  I'm using SAS 9.3 on Solaris but I wouldn't think the SAS version is the issue.  Can you log onto the server directly and run an "ls" command using that same wildcard?  The only other think I can think of would be an Access Control List defined on some other file in that directory...

Answer (score 0):

I think that in order to use wildcards to assign multiple files into a single fileref, you need to wrap the files in parentheses... e.g.

```
filename multi ("myfiles*.txt")
```

Comment: My code without parentheses works (with and without the wildcard) in a different environment, so it can't be that. So if it works in one environment and not in another, that suggests to me that there must be a difference between the environments.